# Filtering through 3 arrays to sort data

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs

I am working on a project that let's you sort through items based on the tags selected. Here is the problem I have been stuck on:

I have an array of items. Each item is an object that has a property of tags. The tags property is an array of the tags associated with that item.

There is a dropdown component that let's you select which tags you want to narrow your results down to. You can have several tags selected at once. The dropdown is an array of tags. I have everything working except for rendering the items based on the tags selected.

example data (stored in redux):

```
const obj = {

const items = [
    { id: 1, name: "car", tags: ["technology", "vehicle"] },
    {id: 2, name: "bike", tags: ["outdoors"] }
]

const dropdownValues = ["vehicle","indoor","technology", "outdoors"]}
```

The below code renders all of my items onto the page.

```
class ItemCardList extends Component{
    render(){
        let data = this.props.itemsData; //this is all of the items data
        let tags = this.props.tags; //these are the selected dropdown tags stored in redux
        return (
            <Masonry>
                {data.map((item) => {
                    return <div><ItemCard key={item.id} item={item}/></div>
                })}
            </Masonry>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tags: state.items.tags,
    itemsData: state.items.itemsData,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemCardList);
```

My thinking goes along the lines of this (which I know is really confusing):

```
{data.filter((item) => item.tags.map(tag => tag == tagsArray.map(tagArr => tagArr))
```

How can I only render the items with the tags selected? Am I overthinking this? Is there a better approach?

Please let me know if there is anyway I can explain this question better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Array.filter()`, `Array.some()` and `Array.includes()` here:

```
//tells us whether a tag should be shown
const isTagVisible = tag => this.props.tags.includes( tag ); 

//tells us whether an item has any tags that should be shown
const doesItemHaveAnyVisibleTags = item => item.tags.some( isTagVisible ); 

//filters only items that have any tags that should be shown
const filteredItems = items.filter( doesItemHaveAnyVisibleTags );
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you Duncan!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
items.filter(
   item => item.tags.some(
        tag => yourDropdownList.indexOf(tag) !== -1
   )
)
```

This will return you all the items that contain the selected tag.

Comment: Questions says there can be multiple tags selected by the user.

Comment: Updated the snippet.